# How to calculate the cost of charging a portable power station?

Tags: power, cost

Can I calculate the cost of charging my portable power station based on the specs for the charge adapter? For example, the adapter shows it rated at 15V @ 3A, and it takes 5 hours to charge. Does that mean I have used 15V×3A ×5h = 225 Wh or 0.225 kWh which cost 21.7 cents per kWh or about 5 cents? That seems low for a 240 Wh unit.

Comment: That's what people mean when they say modern civilization is built on cheap energy. Think about what you pay to keep a light on all day. That was too expensive for most of human history.

Comment: this is correct if charging current stays constant during all the charge time. but this is not. I think better measure is to knowing battery capacity and the percentage it has been filled. This is can be a better estimate if battery capacity doesn't degraded from it's rated.

Comment: 0.225 kWh is exactly the same as 225 Wh.   Are you asking why it isn't exactly 240 Wh?

Answer (score 1):

0.225 kWh is exactly the same thing as 225 Wh.   *It's an SI thing*.

Further, a kWh in your calculations is exactly the same as a kWh on your electric bill.

So yes, there absolutely is an equivalence, and it is that easy... minus any inefficiency of charging and discharging.

Make sure to be realistic about what those things can actually power. Several times I had to pry my sweetie away from buying a much hyped "solar generator" that would run our refrigerator... for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I calculate the cost of charging my portable power station based on the specs for the charge adapter?

Not really.

The charging current that a battery can accept depends on the state of charge. Modern lithium batteries have a strong dislike for over-charging.

So the chargers use the full rated charge current until the battery reaches its "fully charged" voltage. But at this point the battery is not fully charged yet. The charger switches to constant voltage, to avoid over-charging the battery, and the battery finishes charging at this voltage with lower current.

The typical charging profile of a lithium battery is a high current charge up to about 80%, followed by a top-up charge that can last for several hours at much lower current.

So the total charging time until the green LED lights up doesn't tell you how much time it spent at full power, which means the answer to the question is "no".